# Installing migrations from engine won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake, rails-migrations, rails-engines

I created a new engine in Rails 3.1.3 and apparently there's that rake task that copies over all migrations. I tried following `rake abc:install:migrations` which threw:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'abc:install:migrations'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I also tried `rake abc_engine:install:migrations` with the same result.

Then I read `bundle exec rake railties:install:migrations` or `bundle exec rake railties:install:migrations FROM=abc_engine` should do the trick too but no success. Nothing was copied even though no error was thrown.

My migrations are located in db/migrate/ within the engine folder and I ran all commands above from spec/dummy/

Does anyone know how to use this new rake task in order to copy migrations from the engine?

Comment: I'm stuck like you, the documentation is really lacking here!

Answer (score 10):

I ran this instead:

```
rake railties:install:migrations
```

And my migrations were copied from the engine.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got found/got lucky with my (similar) issue. For the first error, it just disappeared, not sure why. Then I figured out that I didn't created the migrations using the usual file name format, so the `ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations` method was ignoring them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that migraitons are part of activerecord, I don't have it in my project so that was not working :/

Answer (score 2):

If the app you're mounting the engine to doesn't already have ActiveRecord (i.e. you're introducing ActiveRecord to your host app for the first time by mounting the engine), you can get this error as well. Specifically, you'll get this error if you don't have `require "active_record/railtie"` in your `application.rb`, or if it's commented out. That line is what enables the `rake railties:install:migrations` task, which is defined [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/212481b490bcd5db77aae1a0a338e25eedc98471/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L357). `rake railties:install:migrations` is, in turn, called by the `rake abc_engine:install:migrations` task [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/212481b490bcd5db77aae1a0a338e25eedc98471/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb#L627).

Tl;dr: try adding `require "active_record/railtie"` to your `application.rb` if it's not already there.